# Making runtime configurations in parent docker image

Tags: docker

I have image `A` that have something like this in Dockerfile

```
ENV LOGGING_LEVEL=error
ENTRYPOINT python setup_logging.py && /bin/bash
```

Then I want to create image `B` based on `A` but with another logging level, e.g.

```
ENV LOGGING_LEVEL=debug
```

This actually works but I feel like I'm violating some good docker manners here?

Comment: You can specify environment variables at startup time with `docker run -e` and similar options.  You probably mean `CMD` and not `ENTRYPOINT` here, and you probably want to actually start the application in your image and not an interactive shell.

Comment: No note that image A is just a base image (where the logging logic needs to be used in images that builds on top of A)